# Integrand of a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, terminology, lebesgue-integral

If we have an integral $\int_A f(x)dx$, or what I am more specifically interested in, $\int_A fd\mu$ where $\mu$ is a measure, is the integrand $f$ or is it $f$ **on the domain $A$**, where A is some set (say of real numbers).

Comment: I think it is classical to defined Lebesgue integral w.r.t. the whole space, and then define integrals over measurable subsets either using restriction of the function, or products with indicators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could describe $\int_{A}f\text{d}\mu$, where $f$ is a $\mu$-measurable function and $A$ a $\mu$-measurable set on which $f$ is definite, as follows:

$\int_{A}f\,\text{d}\mu$ is "the integral of $f$ on $A$ with respect to the measure $\mu$, where $f$ is called the integrand of this integral", so that the term "integrand" explicitly depends on a particular integral and it is not useful to say that the integrand is $f$ restricted to $A$ because the integral already contains this information.